# Separate latitude and longitude from PFGeopoint using Parse with iOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am populating a table view with objects form Parse. There is a class row that is a PFGeopoint.
I need to separate the latitude and longitude values from the geopoint to show them on the table view cell.

I have been searching in the Parse documentation and here in SO, but the only approach found is this:

```
PFGeoPoint has latitude and longitude properties. They are both doubles. Just use... theGeoPoint.latitude etc...
```

But in my case, the cell is getting PFObjects like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                        object:(PFObject *)object
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";

    PFTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[PFTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                      reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell to show todo item with a priority at the bottom
    cell.textLabel.text = object[@"restaurant_name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = object [@"cadena"];

    PFImageView *thumbnailImageView = (PFImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:100];

    thumbnailImageView=[[PFImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(9, 9, 30, 30)];
    [thumbnailImageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];


    PFFile *thumbnail = object[@"image"];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.jpg"];
    cell.imageView.file = thumbnail;


    return cell;
}
```

How could I separate the latitude and longitude from an object,like I am doing to get the name row: `object[@"restaurant_name"]`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found the solution. Inside my cellForRowAtIndex method, I need to create a PFGeopoint and then get the values for latitude and longitude,like this:

```
PFGeoPoint *myRestaurant = object[@"restaurant_coordinates"];
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",
                        [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:myRestaurant.latitude]],
                        [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:myRestaurant.longitude]]];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = string;
```